# How can I avoid double line breaks (<br><br>) in a text field (field type: text unformatted long)?

Tags: entities

How can I avoid double line breaks (`<br><br>`) in a text field (field type: text unformatted, long)?

Users write text into this text field. When they hit Enter twice, the result is:
`<br><br>`.
But `<br><br>` is not themable with css, the height of `<br>` can NOT be set with css.

Therefore `<br><br>` should be avoided and paragraphs `<p>` used instead of it. `<br><br>` should never be saved to database.
How can double `<br><br>` be avoided or replaced with `<p>` before the the field is saved?

Comment: Does your Text format have the `Convert line breaks into HTML (i.e. <br> and <p>)` option enabled?

Comment: This is NOT a textformat, so a can NOT enable this option.

This is a field from type "text unformatted long". Unformatted fields do not have any options like those.

Comment: The Plain Long text field is still controlled with the Plain text Text format. But there seem to be bugs and not enough agreement on how to handle different cases:  https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1152216#comment-5875568, https://www.drupal.org/node/1095838, https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1017662

Comment: An answer here might be helpful as a workaround using the  module Advanced Text Formatter: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38666/how-do-i-get-line-breaks-when-using-plain-text-format

Comment: The module "Advanced Text Formatter" solves this problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can style br tag in CSS, but before you need to reset it by using these declarations:

```css
br {
  display: "block";
  content: "";
}
```

Then you can style it as you want, it can be done using margin property, so the code will be such as:

```css
br {
  display: "block";
  content: "";
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```